# Seeking forward/backward GIF

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, gif, animated-gif

I've a GIF and I'm playing it through a lot of available controls like:

- [AnimatedGIFImageSerialization](https://github.com/mattt/AnimatedGIFImageSerialization)
- [FLAnimatedImage](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage)

I'm asking about a way to seek forward/backward in the GIF it self like in video.

Answer (score 0):

The GIF is stored as incremental updates in most of the cases, some GIF files store frames which can support seeking. Most GIFs are stored using incremental shift. to seek a certain position you need to accumulate all frames from frame 0 up to the seek position.

I am not sure if you can find any control that can do that for you.

Comment: I'm not sure that's entirely true, with the case of [FLAnimatedImage](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage) the current frame image and the upcoming cached frame images are the only ones accumulated. Technically, you could descend rather than ascend. I know there was [branch](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage/tree/features/reverse-playback) of FLAnimatedImage looking to incorporate that feature but it doesn't seem to have gotten anywhere.